# what type of sql db can store sound or array data in a column?

Tags: sql, storage, wav

I need to attach, create a new column in a sql db. It should store the numeric numpy representation of a user's voice - numpy array or an image - spectrogram. 
numpy array looks like this:

```
array([[  2.891e-07,   2.548e-03, ...,   8.116e-09,   5.633e-09],
       [  1.986e-07,   1.162e-02, ...,   9.332e-08,   6.716e-09],
       ...,
       [  3.668e-09,   2.029e-08, ...,   3.208e-09,   2.864e-09],
       [  2.561e-10,   2.096e-09, ...,   7.543e-10,   6.101e-10]])
```

I know sql can only store text data, wonder if it s possible to attach or represent shortly the array in a  column.

```
ID |    date     | voice
1    01-01-20      array([[  2.891e-07,   2.548e-03...
2    01-02-20      array([[  2.891e-07,
```

Comment: Depending on which db engine you're using, you could potentially store audio files as BLOBs or similar datatype (e.g., [Postgres Binary Data Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-binary.html).  You could also store filesystem references in the database which point to your audio files.  You an certainly store the arrays as text as you've suggested.

Comment: @varontron yes but storing arrays is ugly.. any other ideas? BLOBS is the best option?

Comment: It always depends on your use case, which could have requirements for performance, security, portability, asset reuse, etc.  There are always trade offs.  BLOBs will work, but I’m sure there are limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your database engine. I give you the answers to 3 of the most common databases I've worked with :

**1. Oracle :**

You can use `BLOB` datatype to store the binary files themselves. Also, if you want to store the array instead of binary file, you can use `CLOB` datatype as well. Similar to `BLOB`, `CLOB` holds big data, but in character format, so its suitable to hold big texts, such as arrays you've mentioned.

[Oracle Large Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_intro.htm)

**2. MySQL :**

The same datatype, `BLOB` can be used in MySQL as well.
`TEXT` (and its derivatives such as `LARGETEXT`) datatype can be used to hold the big array.

[MySQL Large Objects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

**3. PostgreSQL :**

PgSQL does not have BLOB, but another datatype, called `BYTEA` can store binary objects. Also `TEXT` datatype can store large strings in PgSQL.

[PostgreSQL Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/largeobjects.html)

NOTE : Working with binary data in databases requires a mid-tier application to act as a 'translator' between client and server. Get more info in the reference links above.

Also, about the "Shortened Version" of the data in a column, you can insert the first 10 characters (or any arbitrary number that works for you) inside the table. This has different techniques and procedures, depending on your database engine.

Hope this has answered your question.